# show the infowindow on google map by click html link

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Is there a way to activate the info window on google map from the external link? The html and js code is below.

I would like to have a simple external link to activate infowindow of markers.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated

Sajja :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Map</title>
<style>
#map{
    width:640px;
    height: 480px;
    border:6px solid #6f5f5e;
    margin:20px auto 30px auto;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>


    <div class='container'>

  <div id="map">&nbsp;</div>

</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
var markers = [
    ['Marker 1', 13.988719,100.617909],
    ['Marker 2.', 13.662811,100.43758],
    ['Marker 3', 13.744961,100.535073],
    ['Marker 4', 13.801981,100.613864],
    ['Marker 5', 13.767507,100.644024],
];

$(document).ready(function()  {
    var myOptions = {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),myOptions);
    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('img/marker.png',
        new google.maps.Size(65, 32),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        new google.maps.Point(18, 42)
    );
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(pos);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pos,
            map: map,
            icon: image
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use,

```
function infoOpen(i)
{
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i],'click');
}
```

Use this function for `onclick` of an element

eg.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="infoOpen('1');">open it</a>
```

Here I am posting the complete code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&language=en"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function infoOpen(i)
            {

                google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], 'click');
            }
            var gmarkers = [];
            var markers = [];
            markers = [
                ['0', 'Marker 1', 13.988719, 100.617909],
                ['1', 'Marker 2', 13.662811, 100.43758],
                ['2', 'Marker 3', 13.744961, 100.535073],
                ['3','Marker 4', 13.801981, 100.613864],
                ['4', 'Marker 5', 13.767507, 100.644024]];

            $(document).ready(function () {
                var myOptions = {
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControl: false
                };

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
                var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('img/marker.png',
                new google.maps.Size(65, 32),
                new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                new google.maps.Point(18, 42));
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                var marker, i;
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][2], markers[i][3]);
                    var content = markers[i][1];
                    bounds.extend(pos);
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: pos,
                        map: map
                    });
                    gmarkers.push(marker);
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, content) {
                        return function() {
                            infowindow.setContent(content);
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker, content));
                }


                map.fitBounds(bounds);
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            body {
                text-align: center
            }
            #map {
                width:640px;
                height: 480px;
                border:6px solid #6f5f5e;
                margin:20px auto 30px auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="infoOpen('0');">mark 1</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="infoOpen('1');">mark 2</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="infoOpen('2');">mark 3</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="infoOpen('3');">mark 4</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="infoOpen('4');">mark 5</a>

            <div id="map">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have added `gmarkers.push(marker)`

Comment: The answer above worked for me. If you don't want all the logic in the <a> tag you can jquery the onclick in a later <script> tag like:

        $("#meetupDirections").on('click', function () {
            google.maps.event.trigger(meetupMarker, 'click');
        });

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works! http://jsfiddle.net/tinsajja/nXkXA/43/

OK, let say I have many markers on the map. How can I manage the makers into  I have try to put  but it doesn't active the infobox.

Due my coding skill is cut and paste so I searching and come with this http://jsfiddle.net/tinsajja/ezSUF/67/

on the code

```
$('#listdiv').append('<p><a href="javascript:show(' + i + ')" id="link' + i + '">' + locations[i][0] + '</a></p>');
```

I try to add

```
<select><option><a href="javascript:show(' + i + ')"...
```

but the results generated 5 select boxes. Please teach me how to make it.

Thanks,
Sajja